# RailsAdmin vs ActiveAdmin 2016

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get hard decision, and choose between this two CMS gems. It is absolutely incorrect to choose it, based on the frontend design. 
After getting into both, I understood, that the difference nowadays is really thin. Help me and show this difference for proper choice.

I need it for little project ~15-20 models

PS: I'm asking not for holy war, I really need to know what to choose

Comment: can you give the scenario or purpose for why you are comparing these two gems..

Comment: My point of view, ActiveAdmin - easy to configure, RailsAdmin - fancy looking. Now, as for me, I always go with ActiveAdmin, tried RailsAdmin too of course, once.

Comment: i have used both, as per my understanding and experience ActiveAdmin is better than RailsAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I am using ActiveAdmin,its functionality & customization is easy. But as in your project, if you will use 15-20 model, its header layout will be disturbed. So better to use Rails admin, because its view is much better and you can easily use 15-20 model.